# play test resource folders not visible in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, testing, playframework-2.0, classpath, playframework-2.1

After project/Build.scala file is defined as

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(defaultScalaSettings:_*).settings(
    ,resourceDirectory in Test <<= baseDirectory(_ / "test-resources")
)
```

Running `show test:resource-directories` will display

```
[info] List(C:\Users\grigocn\work\reliable-transport-ui\test-resources, C:\Users\grigocn\work\reliable-transport-ui\target\scala-2.9.1\resource_managed\test)
```

But running `eclipsify` will not add the folder to the eclipse project.

How I should configure the project to let the eclipsify plugin know about this resource directory?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the `.settings()` block of your Build.scala:

```
unmanagedClasspath in Test <+= baseDirectory map { bd => Attributed.blank(bd / "test-resources") }
```

This is from a Play 2.1 project, but I don't think the syntax changed between 2.0 and 2.1.